# Outlook trigger randomly stops working

Tags: vba, outlook, triggers, ms-office

Ever morning we get an automated email with today's pricing. I have a trigger set on my outlook session that checks each new email and if it has the subject, starts a script. The problem is, this trigger only sometimes works. I keep the machine running all of the time and outlook open, but I find the trigger just stops working after a period of time. Usually I just have to restart outlook - and sometimes I just have to modify and re-save the code.

Is there anything I can change to make this trigger more reliable?

Note: I do not have access to task scheduler.

UPDATE: I've started getting the following alert:

> The file C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\Me@host.com.ost
>   is in use and cannot be accessed. Close any application that is using
>   this file and then try again. You might need to restart your computer.

Hitting OK doesn't interrupt the script from running - but is it pausing the trigger going forward perhaps?

Here's the script:

```
'Placed in Microsoft Outlook Objects > ThisOutlookSession

Private WithEvents olInboxItems As Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Set olInboxItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub olInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    If TypeOf Item Is mailItem Then
        Call handleMessage(Item.EntryID)
    End If
End Sub

Public Function handleMessage(strMailItemID As String)
    ' This function takes an email ID and determines whether it's our pricing sheet email.

    Dim mailItem As Outlook.mailItem
    Dim path As String, targetSubj As String
    Dim result As Boolean
    result = False
    targetSubj = "Today's Pricing"
    Set mailItem = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strMailItemID)

    Debug.Print (mailItem.Subject) 'I use this to test if my script is working
                                   'I find that it logs the subject and then simply cuts off. 

    If (Mid(mailItem.Subject, 1, Len(targetSubj)) = targetSubj) Then
        Debug.Print ("Grabbed Target " & Date)
        path = "C:\pathToPricing\Pricing.xls"
        mailItem.Attachments.Item(1).SaveAsFile path
        Call runExcelMacro("C:\pathToPricing\pricingAuto.xlsm", "processPricing")
        result = True

    End If

    handleMessage = result
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The [ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609(v=office.15).aspx) event is not fired when a large number of items are added to the folder at once, more than 16 - this is a known issue in Outlook.

Instead, you may consider creating a rule in Outlook and then assign a VBA macro sub to run. It should look like the following one:

```
public sub test(mail as MailItem)
   ' do whatever you need
end sub
```

Another solution is to use a timer for checking for new emails.

Also you may find the following series of articles helpful:

- [Outlook NewMail event unleashed: the challenge (NewMail, NewMailEx, ItemAdd)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/03/outlook-newmail-event/)
- [Outlook NewMail event: solution options](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/10/24/outlook-newmail-solution-options/)
- [Outlook NewMail event and Extended MAPI: C# example](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/01/outlook-newmail-extended-mapi/)
- [Outlook NewMail unleashed: writing a working solution (C# example)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/11/10/outlook-newmail-custom-solution/)

Comment: Originally I used NewMailEx - but I found this even less reliable. I'll look into the other solutions you've proposed. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is no solution, you can run Application_Startup from a button, when you remember or when you notice the trigger is broken.

Delete Private so you have this.

```
Sub Application_Startup()
    Set olInboxItems = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub
```

Put Application_Startup on a button in the Quick Access Toolbar or a ribbon.

You could put Private back if you wish. The button should still work.