# Outlook VBA Code stops firing after some time

Tags: vba, events, outlook

The code below works perfectly:

```
Option Explicit

Dim myOlApp As New Outlook.Application

Public WithEvents myOlInspectors As Outlook.Inspectors

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Initialize_handler
End Sub

Public Sub Initialize_handler()
    Set myOlInspectors = myOlApp.Inspectors
End Sub

Private Sub myOlInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
    Set msg = Inspector.CurrentItem
    If msg.Size = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "New message"             ' TEST LINE
            msg.CC = "email@email.com"
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

However, after a few hours of works. It suddenly stops firing (and I don't get any error).

Is there something I missunderstand about the code?

Is there something about Outlook.Inspectors, that makes it stop launching for some reason?

Comment: Suggested workarounds. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548203/withevents-object-in-outlook-vba-eventually-fails-to-raise-event. You could run `Initialize_handler` from say `Application_ItemSend` or manually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29972061/outlook-trigger-randomly-stops-working.

Answer (score 0):

Your event method may fail if no item is currently open.

To add a `CC` recipient, you should do something like

```
Set myRecipient = msg.Recipients.Add("email@email.com") 
 
myRecipient.Type = olCC
```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably the event is fired properly, but you have got an error in the code at runtime. The `NewInspector` event is not the best place for getting the `CurrentItem` property:

```
Private Sub myOlInspectors_NewInspector(ByVal Inspector As Outlook.Inspector)
    Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
    Set msg = Inspector.CurrentItem
    If msg.Size = 0 Then
        'MsgBox "New message"             ' TEST LINE
            msg.CC = "email@email.com"
    End If
End If
```

Especially the following line of code could raise an error at runtime:

```
If Inspector.CurrentItem.Class = olMail Then
```

Instead, consider using the first Inspector`s [Activate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.inspector.activate(even)) event which is fired when an inspector becomes the active window, either as a result of user action or through program code. So, in the first Activate event you could get item's properties without a problem.

Also you may consider adding [On Error statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement#:%7E:text=time%20error%20occurs.-,On%20Error%20Resume%20Next,Error%20GoTo%20when%20accessing%20objects.) to the code so you could be aware why the event "is not fired".